# Rigidity/flexibility of Nil-, Sol-, $\widetilde{\rm SL}_2$- structures on closed 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, 3-manifolds, geometric-structures

It is known that closed spherical and hyperbolic 3-manifolds are rigid. I.e., if two such manifolds are diffeomorphic, then they are isometric (moreover, I think, that every diffeomorphism is isotopic to an isometry). On the other hand, closed Euclidean 3-manifolds admit non-trivial Teichmüller spaces of Euclidean structures. What is known about more exotic Thurston's geometries, namely, Nil, $\widetilde{\rm SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and Sol?

Let $M$ be a closed 3-manifold, $G$ be one of the mentioned Lie groups and $\mathcal T(M, G)$ be the space of the respective geometric structures on $M$ up to isotopy (say, endowed with the topology inherited from the respective space of representations of $\pi_1(M)$). Could it be more than one point? If yes, what is known about it?

Comment: Yes, typically not rigid, but there are some rigid exceptions among small Seifert manifolds. You can start by looking at Teichmuller spaces of base-orbifolds of Seifert manifolds.

Comment: One issue comes from the non-uniqueness of metric on the simply connected cover $G/K$ itself. For instance, for $G=\mathrm{SOL}$ I don't know if there is a "better" choice (there is just a very weak condition of being invariant by $K$, but then $K$ is finite of order $8$).

Comment: A key point in recent work of Bamler and Kleiner on Smale conjecture for 3-manifold modelled on Nil is the proof (in lemma 2.4 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.03302) that any non-Haken closed 3-manifold modelled on Nil has a unique unit volume Nil-structure up to isometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\PSLt}{\widetilde{\mathrm{PSL}_2}}$Manifolds with $\PSLt$ geometry can have non-trivial moduli.  For example, suppose that $S$ is a closed, connected, oriented surface with genus at least two.  Let $M$ be a copy of $\mathrm{UT}S$, the unit tangent bundle of $S$.  Then there is a (distinct) $\PSLt$ structure on $M$ coming from every (distinct) hyperbolic structure on $S$.

The argument is similar when $M$ is instead the unit tangent bundle over a hyperbolic orbifold $B$.  The exception is when $B$ is a triangle orbifold: that is, a copy of the two-sphere with three cone points having angles $2\pi/p$, $2\pi/q$, and $2\pi/r$ so that $1/p + 1/q + 1/r > 1$.  In this case $B$ has a unique hyperbolic structure (the double of the corresponding triangle); also $\mathrm{UT}B$ has a unique $\PSLt$ structure.

The story for $\mathbb{H}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ geometry follows similar lines.

Comment: What do you call PSL geometry? Do you mean $\widetilde{\mathrm{PSL}_2}$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that - but that takes a long time to typeset...